# JSONB Recursive Search and Replace by Key

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Given an arbitrarily nested jsonb document, how can all instances of a specific key be replaced by another document.

For example:

```sql
select '{
    "good_key": {
        "critical": "info",
        "bad_key": {
            "worthless": "trash"
        }
    },
    "bad_key": {
        "more": "garbage"
    }
}'::jsonb
```

replacing all instances of `"bad_key"` and it's contents, with `{"substitute_key": {"some": "info"}}`

Resulting in

```
'{
    "good_key": {
        "critical": "info",
        "substitute_key": {
           "some": "info"
        }
    },
    "substitute_key": {
        "some": "info"
    }
}'
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:recursive-cte]? Can you use an SQL function?

Comment: absolutely! a function would be preferable. poor choice of label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a combination of [`jsonb_each`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) and [`jsonb_object_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

```
CREATE FUNCTION jsonb_replace_by_key(obj jsonb, search text, substitute jsonb) RETURNS jsonb
STRICT LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
  SELECT CASE jsonb_typeof(obj)
    WHEN 'object' THEN
      (SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, CASE WHEN key = search
          THEN substitute
          ELSE jsonb_replace_by_key(value, search, substitute)
        END)
      FROM jsonb_each(obj))
    WHEN 'array' THEN
      (SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_replace_by_key(el, search, substitute))
      FROM jsonb_array_elements(obj) el)
    ELSE
      obj
 END;
$$;
```

Since you don't want to just replace the value of the property, but completely remove the property and add something else when it existed, use the following query in the `object` case instead:

```
SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, jsonb_replace_by_key(value, search, substitute))
  || CASE WHEN obj ? search THEN substitute ELSE '{}' END
FROM jsonb_each(obj)
WHERE key <> search
```

<sub>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3867690ec07271d22d6273ae09ab6be4))</sub>